# How to create an API inside a Blazor Server project

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, webassembly

I developed a Blazor server application where users can read/write to underlying database with EFcore.
Now I also developed an Android application, that should also have access to this database.
So I need to create an API-Controller that handles this requests.
What would be the best way:

1. Create an Api-Controller inside the BlazorServer application?
2. Change to Blazor WASM, and create a ApiController in the Server part?
3. Create a completely seperate AspNetCore Web Api that handles this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Based on the information you've provided, 1 - Create the API in the Server Project.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the "How to" question from the title :

In Program.cs, below  `app.MapBlazorHub();`, add

```cs
 app.MapControllers();
```

And then add a **Controllers** folder and one or more api controllers.

Be aware that an error in an API route will not result in a 404 but it will return the 'sorry, nothing here' page instead. Usually resulting in a *`<` is an invalid start of JSON error*.